# adding ngsanitize to mean.io

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io, ngsanitize

I am new to the mean stack and am trying to add ngSanitize.  I installed on the command line and see the library inside /bower_components/ but the angular-sanitize.js script isn't loading on the app.  Am I missing a step for this?  I tried adding the module to the default modules in /public/init.js but still no luck.

The bower.json file looks correct too:

> {   "name": "mean",   "version": "0.4.0",   "dependencies": {
>       "jquery": "1.x",
>       "jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
>       "angular": "latest",
>       "angular-resource": "latest",
>       "angular-cookies": "latest",
>       "angular-mocks": "latest",
>       "angular-route": "latest",
>       "bootstrap": "3.1.1",
>       "angular-bootstrap": "0.11.0",
>       "angular-ui-router": "#master",
>       "angular-sanitize": "~1.2.22"   } }

Comment: make sure it is actually included in your index.html

Comment: yeah that is the problem, all other scripts in bower_components are appeneded to the index.html file <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Depending on your grunt config, running 'grunt serve' could append the automatically to index.html

Comment: if your issue is solved, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ngSanitize is included in your index.html file. Running

```
bower install
```

will not do that automatically. Depending on your Gruntfile, running

```
grunt serve
```

might add it for you

Comment: thanks, that added jquery-ui that had gone missing but for some reason isn't adding sanitize even though the library is there.

Comment: the answer wasn't the fix so I am not accepting it.